# UI not refreshing

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my updated code with UI still not refreshing. What am I doing wrong?
I moved the setState function and also deleted the initState

```
class IncludeObject extends StatefulWidget {


const IncludeObject({
Key key,
this.title,
```

}) `: super(key: key);
final String title;

@override
_IncludeObject createState() => _IncludeObject();`

```
class _IncludeObject extends State<IncludeObject> {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.5),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xffDEDEDE), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
    child: Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Text(
              widget.title.toString(),
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontFamily: "Montserrat Regular", fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.close_outlined,
                size: 20,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  for (int i = 0; i <= includedList.length; i++) {
                    if (includedList[i].title == widget.title) {
                      includedList.removeAt(i);
                      included.removeAt(i);
                      print("removed");
                    }
                  }
                });
              }),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

first it's not so good to have a **setState** inside your initState (read more about widgets life cycle)
now why this problem is happening is because you're not calling setState to update the UI with the new data, and simply to do that just add the code in the **onPressed** inside a `setState`, like this

```
      onPressed: () {
           setState(() {
             for (int i = 0; i <= includedList.length; i++) {
              if (includedList[i].title == widget.title) {
                includedList.removeAt(i);
                included.removeAt(i);
                _isRemoved = true;
                print("removed");
                print(_isRemoved);
              }
            }
            });
          }),
```

Comment: I tried that, but I am still not able to get the tag to be removed. ie the UI isnt being refreshed unless I hot reload then the tag does go

Comment: Can you edit the question with the new code?

Comment: I have updated it to the new code. Could you please take a look

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setState` after you remove the item.

setState() tells flutter to re-run the build and the changes are thus reflected.

You can call it after you remove your item.

```
     onPressed: () {
            for (int i = 0; i <= includedList.length; i++) {
              if (includedList[i].title == widget.title) {
               

                includedList.removeAt(i);
                included.removeAt(i);

                _isRemoved = true;

                setState(() {});

                print("removed");
                print(_isRemoved);
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: I tried that, but I am still not able to get the tag to be removed. ie the UI isnt being refreshed unless I hot reload then the tag does go